# opencpu app is not deployed on public server

Tags: r, github, opencpu

I am a beginner to opencpu service and I want to deploy my app on opencpu public server. I tried using GitHub webhook to deploy my app as the opencpu guide says on their [website](https://www.opencpu.org/cloud.html). According to opencpu after pushing R package code to GitHub and configuring webhook the app will be deployed on their server and can be used using http://yourname.ocpu.io/ but in my case, I didn't find my app on the URL

> "Github App sdiwash/hello not installed on this server"

and got this message.